# is it possible to stop NuGet package manager from trying to access the web?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a virtual machine that cannot see the internet, with VS2012 installed. It has a local directory with some NuGet packages in it, and NuGet is configured to look at that as its only package source. All works well except that whenever I open the "Manage NuGet Packages" dialog, it hangs for about a minute or two. Wireshark tells me it is making repeated DNS requests to the original package sources (e.g. www.gdal.org). Can I tell it not to do this? It's not as though it is going to get anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried adding an entry in `hosts` redirecting to localhost, etc.  If it gets an invalid response it might just stop looking, as opposed to waiting for timeouts

Comment: I did think of that, I haven't tried it because it doesn't seem to scale well. It would work as a last resort though.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a last resort.  But I think anything else would be editing config files somewhere (for nuget) on the target machine or editing the registry, and pointing it at localhost.  I bet the searching is hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be adding the "Clear" element to the  section in nuget.config file.

For more details, please refer to https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3706.

Comment: Thanks, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the auto updater from **Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Settings**.

[image]

and removing package sources -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the  response. NuGet.org is unticked, which seems ot be all I can to to remove it. Anyway, it is not going to nuget.org, it is going to e.g. gdal.org. Also, it does not seem to be a problem at build time, only in the package manager GUI.